# How to negate Airflow sensor task result?

Tags: airflow

Is there a built-in facility or some operator that will run a sensor and negate its status?  I am writing a workflow that needs to detect that an object does *not* exist in order to proceed to eventual success.  I have a sensor, but it detects when the object *does* exist.

For instance, I would like my workflow to detect that an object does not exist.  I need almost exactly [S3KeySensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.5/_api/airflow/sensors/s3_key_sensor/index.html), except that I need to negate its status.

Comment: Please assume I configure the sensor retries appropriately for my use-case.  In this case, I will be able to probe just once.

Comment: Sensors wait till something happens. Your use case sound different. Is your issue that you wish to check if key exist in buckets (just once)?

Comment: @EladKalif I would like to wait until the object is not there.  (Yes, a timeout will be involved.)

Comment: @EladKalif would I get a better answer if I asked how to run an **operator** and continue the workflow only if it fails?  I could live with that, too...

Answer (score 1):

The use case you are describing is checking key in S3, if exist wait otherwise continue workflow. As you mentioned this is a Sensor use case. The `S3Hook` has function [`check_for_key`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/27a80511ec3ffcf036354741bd0bfe18d4b4a471/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/s3.py#L433) that checks if key exist so all needed is just to wrap it with Sensor poke function..

A simple basic implementation would be:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
from airflow.sensors.base import BaseSensorOperator

class S3KeyNotPresentSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    """ Waits for a key to not be present in S3. """

    template_fields: Sequence[str] = ('bucket_key', 'bucket_name')

    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        bucket_key: str,
        bucket_name: Optional[str] = None,
        aws_conn_id: str = 'aws_default',
        verify: Optional[Union[str, bool]] = None,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bucket_name = bucket_name
        self.bucket_key = [bucket_key] if isinstance(bucket_key, str) else bucket_key
        self.aws_conn_id = aws_conn_id
        self.verify = verify
        self.hook: Optional[S3Hook] = None

    def poke(self, context: 'Context'):
        return not self.get_hook().check_for_key(self.bucket_key, self.bucket_name)

    def get_hook(self) -> S3Hook:
        """Create and return an S3Hook"""
        if self.hook:
            return self.hook

        self.hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id=self.aws_conn_id, verify=self.verify)
        return self.hook
```

Comment: Cool, thanks!  I was hoping for a more generic (and preferably built-in) facility which would work on top of many different operators or sensors.  This solution works great, but I need to wrap every `check_*` operation in a hook to get a sensor.  I was hoping for something higher-order, more like an [Rx `map` operation](https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html).

Comment: @ariels the code I provided is a working solution to the use case as you described in your question. You can always customize it to your additional needs

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going another way.  I can use the [`trigger_rule` argument](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#concepts-trigger-rules) of (any) Task -- by setting it to `one_failed` or `all_failed` on the *next* task I can play around with the desired status.

For example,

```py
    file_exists = FileSensor(task_id='exists', timeout=3, poke_interval=1, filepath='/tmp/error', mode='reschedule')
    sing = SmoothOperator(task_id='sing', trigger_rule='all_failed')

    file_exists >> sing
```

It requires no added code or operator, but has the possible disadvantage of being somewhat surprising.

Replying to myself in the hope that this may be useful to someone else.  Thanks!